# How to normalize table with multiple similar columns (day1, day2, day3...)?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a database named BusinessPass and a website that users can use to create Business Passes. Below is the web form.

Date | Time From | Time To | Location

The problem is the table design. Below is my proposed table design.

BusinessPassId, UserID, Date1, From1, To1, Location1, Date2, From2, To2, Location2.... and so on. There would be a maximum of up to 31 days. So I would have 126 columns total. Is there a better way to design this?

Answer (score 1):

The better way is the original design with 1 column for Date, From and To.
If data is large size than you can partition the table on the basis of date(month wise or day wise).

```
ID, Date, From, To, Location
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use two separate tables

- `Business_Pass_Header` : Contains infos about the business pass
- `Business_Pass_Detail` : Contains dates ranges

And finally you use a foreign key to link up the two tables. This ways you can have 0 to N dates ranges.